# MS Word Page Setup Dialog box

Tags: vb.net

I need help with page setup dialog..
is there any way that i can pass some value to openpagedialog in word using vb.net.

my code is

```
Dim dialog As Word.Dialog = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Dialogs(Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogFilePageSetup)
            dialog.DefaultTab = WdWordDialogTab.wdDialogFilePageSetupTabPaper

            dialog.Show()
```

i need select the tray automatically when this dialog is open...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this works or not because my printer has only one tray.
Let me know if this is right

```
....
Dim wd as Word.Application = new Word.Application()
Dim doc As Word.Document = wd.Documents.open("yourdoc.doc")
doc.PageSetup.FirstPageTray = Word.WdPaperTray.wdPrinterMiddleBin
wd.Visible = true
Dim dialog As Word.Dialog = wd.Dialogs(Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogFilePageSetup)
dialog.DefaultTab = Word.WdWordDialogTab.wdDialogFilePageSetupTabPaper
dialog.Show()
....
```

basically I set the tray on the PageSetup of the current document. When I open the dialog the tray is selected from the current document data.

Comment: Its very close. the only thing that i didn't understand is that   doc.PageSetup.FirstPageTray = Word.WdPaperTray.wdPrinterMiddleBin
is selecting the automatic tray, but i need to select tray1 ... any help please????? thanks

Comment: Check this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdpapertray(v=office.11).aspx